# What's the Japanese phrase for "for the occasion of" or "for use in"

Tags: word-choice

I work at a shoe store here in the US, and every now and again, especially during Summer, we get a decent amount of Japanese customers. I more or less know most of the business phrases, but I'm not entirely sure how to specify what they are looking for. So say the conversation goes like this...

> 「いらっしゃいませ！なにかをさがしですか。」
> 「ヒールはどちらですか。」
> 「ヒールはこちらのコーナーにあります。」(or would 通路 be better?)

Afterwards, I want to ask them what heels they are looking for in particular to better redirect them. (Are you looking for heels for a party, for your job, for a day out, etc), but I'm not sure how to ask. So basically, how would I ask "what occasion are you shopping for? Are you looking for heels for a party, for work, etc?"

Answer (score 2):

I guess that would be like

> どのような場面でお使いになるものをおさがしですか？

or more simply

> どのようなものをおさがしですか？

also, I guess it's common to say

> (よそ行き/普段履き/仕事用 etc.)のものをおさがしですか？

if you can guess.